# Unity 2D: Area Color Inverse Effect

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a GameObejct that if active reverses the colors of anything behind it. Ideally, this GameObject expands from its centre point to a certain size radius when it appears/becomes active.

So imagine a circle whose Scale increases from x=0 and y=0 to x=5 and y=5 gradually over 1 or 2 seconds and reverses the colors of anything behind. Doesn't exactly matter how long or how big the actual circle is, just an example of the idea. I tried just creating a GameObect with a mask and a shader I found online, but t didn't work at all and I still wasn't even sure how to animate the expansion.

Does anyone have any idea on how I could make this dream effect of mine a reality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a shader that does nothing except invert the color.

The important part is `Alpha:Blend` and `Blend OneMinusDstColor Zero`.

```c
Shader "Custom/Invert" 
{
    Properties 
    {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader 
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent" }
        LOD 200
        Blend OneMinusDstColor Zero

        PASS
        {
            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 3.0 Alpha:Blend

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            fixed4 _Color;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = float2(0,0);
                return o;
            }
        
            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                return _Color;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

You can put this on any sprite or 3D object to get this effect:
[image]

As for the animation, King's answer is nice and simple. Alternatively you could animate the scale by code:

```
public class Scale : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Update ()
    {
        var scale = Mathf.Sin(Time.timeSinceLevelLoad / 4f) * 20;
        this.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale, scale, 1);
    }
}
```

This particular code will make the sprite 'pulse'. Like this:

[image: Pulse]

I think you should be able to make your own scaling script from this example.

Comment: I used King's way of animating the final version of the effect and your transparent shader works flawlessly. Thank you! I have another question though. Is it possible to have a shader that works the same way but transforms the HUE of what is behind by 180 degrees rather than invert the colors? I believe this would have been better for me, but my bad for not testing enough in Photoshop first.

Comment: I'm sure there's a way. Would you mind posting a different question (if there is not one already) and linking back to this one for reference?

Comment: Also please put the link to the question here :)

Comment: Here is the link to the new questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807069/unity-2d-area-hue-shift-effect

Comment: Again, if you can help, it will be greatly aprpeciated. If not, well, I am still more than grateful for the spent time.

Answer (score 1):

Select your GameObject->Window->Animation->Animation->Create->Save->Add Property->Transform->Scale. At your 0:00 keyframe set your scale for x,y,z to 1. Click over to your 1:00 keyframe and set your scale for x,y,z to 2. Press play and your animation should loop from scale of 1 to 2.

Comment: Thank you! Quite simple and I actually understood how the Animator works a bit more. I only used pre-drawn animations until now.